# Proof of $\forall B \!\in\! R\;\forall C\!\in\! R \left\{\forall A\!\in\! R[(0< A <1) \rightarrow (A \cdot B \le C)] \rightarrow (B \le C) \right \}$

Tags: real-analysis, first-order-logic

I was reading Bartle's "The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure" when I came across the following inference:

[image]

This, for me, can be transated as:

$\forall B \!\in\! R\;\forall C\!\in\! R \left\{\forall A\!\in\! R\;[(0< A <1) \rightarrow (A \cdot B \le C)] \rightarrow (B \le C) \right \}$

My question is: **Why is this sentence true?**

I know $B$ is the supremum of $A \cdot B$, and I have been told that this fact proves the sentence, but I cannot see how.

Comment: The sentence as currently written is not true.  Let $A=\frac{1}{10}$, $B=5$, and $C=2$.

Comment: What should I do to adapt it to the situation mentioned in the textbook? I thought about putting a $\forall A$ before $(A \cdot B \le C)$, but I'm not sure if this is enough....

Comment: I used logical symbols in an effort to generalize my question...I thought that would make my post more useful to other users in Stack Exchange....

Comment: It would be better to avoid logical symbols. But the shape would be $\forall B\forall C(\forall A(AB\le C)\implies (B\le C))$.  I have left out the condition on $A$ because typing in comments is unpleasant. You can fill it in.

Comment: I'll update the question, then. Why is it better to avoid logical symbols?

Comment: Because they often make things more confusing, not less.

Comment: The way to insert the condition on $A$ in semiformal language is to replace my $AB\le C$ above by $(0\lt A\lt 1)\implies (AB\le C)$. Side comment, if I were using logical symbols I would not use caps for the variables.

Comment: OK. Updated again.

Comment: More or less OK now. Now to the answer. Suppose to the contrary that $B\gt C$. Let $\frac{B}{C}=k\gt 1$, and let $1\lt t\lt k$. Let $A=\frac{1}{t}$. Then $AB\gt C$, contradicting the hypothesis.  Note I am tacitly assuming that $B$ and $C$ are positive, which has not been mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of this set
$$
S = \left\{ \alpha \int \varphi \, d\mu : 0 < \alpha < 1 \right\}.
$$
The book shows that 
$$
\lim \int f_n \, d\mu
$$
is an upper bound for $S$. Then, as you said
$$
\sup S = \int \varphi \, d\mu.
$$
By definition, the supremum will be smaller than all other upper bounds. Hence
$$
\int \varphi \, d\mu = \sup S \leq \lim \int f_n \, d\mu.
$$